# Teensy USB Core on Leonardo

Tags: arduino-leonardo, teensy

The USB Serial speed on the teensy is WAY faster then on the Leonardo. Looks like because they have greatly improved the USB code. Has anyone had any luck using the Teensy core libraries on a Leonardo? I would imagine it should work as the hardware is basically the same.

Comment: Have you tried selecting a higher speed in your serial client?

Comment: Yes, I've cranked it all the way to 1Mbps.

Comment: Looking at the schematics of both, I don't see why it wouldn't work. Just note that e.g. you'll lose the tx and rx led functionality (which might account to the slower speed), but you could reuse those leds for something else (-:. Also be aware that pin numbering is a bit different.

Comment: Unless you are comparing to the teensy 2.0 (not +), the hardware is much different (i.e. microprocessor) - that alone could account for a large performance difference

Comment: The discontinued Arduino Leonardo uses an ATmega32U, (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardLeonardo)  as is the Teensy2.0, which, USB-hardware-wise is very similar to the AT90USB1286.  Teensy's hardware USB system acts as a virtual serial port and completely ignores the Serial.begin(xxxx) baud rate and operates at a full 12Mbi ratet:  https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_serial.html